# Left Join - In Eloquent

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent

I would like to connect user table and like table based on the user_id

So I have this Model

**user.php**

```
public function like()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Like', 'users_id', 'id');
}
```

**like.php**

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User', 'id', 'user_id');
}
```

and my query

```
$mentor = $this->article->with("articlecategory")->with(["user.like"])->orderby("id", "DESC")->get();
```

I would like to return the 'likes' table inside the 'user' but it doesnt work. I would like to left join it.

What am I doing wrong?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you want to get all the likes from the `likes` table for the user ID?

Comment: only the user_id that is logged in. I would like to know if the user already liked the article thats why I want to left join it but I dont know how in eloquent

EDITED**

Sorry yes, I would like to get all the likes for the user ID

Comment: I updated my answer, I would like to get all the likes for that User ID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you need to use `one-to-many` relation to get likes for the specified user. And to do that you need to use `hasMany()` method on the `User` model as the following:

```
<?php

public function likes()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Like', 'user_id', 'id');
}
```

Comment: I dont know why its still not showing under user's array.

Comment: Oh, I saw my error now. I got my 'users' typo. thanks!